# Json Values Append Array but ViewDidLoad it seem Empty

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am working in iOS and when I take JSON datas , I print it with no error in the function and append it a String array ( I did it correctly )

But if I want to reach to String array later the json Function it seem empty array . For testing I printed the array in a Button Action then it worked for me but I want to use in String Datas in other Function when Json Function ends.

The Codes:

```
func getAllDataFromURL()
{
    var i : Int = 0;
    var urlDatas : [String] = allJsonDatas.getAllTours();
    for(i = 0 ; i < allJsonDatas.getAllTours().count ; i += 1)
    {
        Alamofire.request(.GET, urlDatas[i]).responseJSON
        {(response) -> Void in

            if let arrivedData = response.result.value
            {
                print("********")
                print(arrivedData["generalTourDistrict"] as! String);
                print(arrivedData["otherTourDistrict"] as! String);
                print(arrivedData["photoURLS"] as! [String]);
                print(arrivedData["subTourDistrict"] as! String);
                print(arrivedData["tourCalendar"] as! String);
                print(arrivedData["tourDistrict"] as! String);
                print(arrivedData["tourName"] as! String);
                self.tryingSomething.appendContentsOf(arrivedData["photoURLS"] as! [String]);
                print("********\n")

            }
        }
    }
}
```

And viewDidLoad is

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  Alamofire.Request.addAcceptableImageContentTypes(acceptableContentTypes);


    self.getAllDataFromURL();
    self.printTheJsonDatas();

}
```

For Example , in getAllDataFromURL() function I can print it correctly.

This is the result for url data from the json:

```
["https://acenta.dominant.com.tr//dominant/webout/R12/php/product/img.php?path=L2QvMS9jcmkvc295a3VsL3VydW4vMDAvMjIvMTIvaW1hZ2UvL3VfMDAyMjEyLjAwMDAxLmpwZWc=&rx=650&ry=400", "https://acenta.dominant.com.tr//dominant/webout/R12/php/product/img.php?path=L2QvMS9jcmkvc295a3VsL3VydW4vMDAvMjIvMTIvaW1hZ2UvL3VfMDAyMjEyLjAwMDA2LmpwZWc=&rx=650&ry=400"]
```

But `printTheJsonDatas()` prints an empty array like -> [ ]

```
func printTheJsonDatas()
{
  print(tryingSomething)
  //tryingSomething : [String] 
}
```

Surprisingly , when I put `printTheJsonDatas()` into `buttonClickedAction`, then it worked as I said before.

I think the problem is about threads but I can not say anything clearly .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getAllDataFromURL()` runs asynchronously with a completion block (known as a closure in swift, or callback on other languages). The order of events is:

1. `getAllDataFromURL()`
2. `printTheJsonDatas()`
3. `Alamofire.request()`
4. (wait for AF response)
5. `self.tryingSomething.appendContentsOf(...)`

If you want the print function to work correctly, you'll need to call it inside the completion block of the AF request, e.g.:

```
func getAllDataFromURL()
{
    var i : Int = 0;
    var urlDatas : [String] = allJsonDatas.getAllTours();
    for(i = 0 ; i < allJsonDatas.getAllTours().count ; i += 1)
    {
        Alamofire.request(.GET, urlDatas[i]).responseJSON
        {(response) -> Void in

            if let arrivedData = response.result.value
            {
                self.tryingSomething.appendContentsOf(arrivedData["photoURLS"] as! [String]);
                //
                self.printTheJsonDatas();
                // ^
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You could also rewrite `getAllDataFromURL()` with a closure to be asynchronous (the more appropriate way to write this, I'd say):

```
func getAllDataFromURL(completion: (result: Array) -> Void) {
    ...
    var returnArray = []
    // ^ here this is a local variable, doesn't need to be global anymore
    returnArray.appendContentsOf(arrivedData["photoURLS"] as! [String]);
    completion(returnArray)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment sir  , so i need to use json datas in other function , tryingSomething is a global variable , what should i do ?

Comment: Then you'll need to rewrite `getAllDataFromURL()` to support a completion block and call it when the function is done. See https://thatthinginswift.com/completion-handlers/ for one, or google "Swift Closures" or "Swift Completion Blocks"

Comment: I write with completion block  `getAllDataFromURL()` but it did not work , i guess json operations works swiftly and other function takes the array as empty array

Comment: Can you post that updated code then? Unless you mean `getAllDataFromURL()` as you have it in the OP, in which case that does not have a closure. See update.

Comment: I will update after the last trying with comp. block , Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are calling both your web service request and print functions consecutive like they are both syncronous but they are not. When you make a web servic request with `Alamofire` it works asyncronous. So you can not expect it to finish in a certain time in future. What you should do is call your print function in `.response` block of the `Alamofire` request:

```
func getAllDataFromURL()
{
    var i : Int = 0;
    var urlDatas : [String] = allJsonDatas.getAllTours();
    for(i = 0 ; i < allJsonDatas.getAllTours().count ; i += 1)
    {
        Alamofire.request(.GET, urlDatas[i]).responseJSON
        {(response) -> Void in

            if let arrivedData = response.result.value
            {
                self.tryingSomething.appendContentsOf(arrivedData["photoURLS"] as! [String]);
                self.printTheJsonDatas();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

An other problem with your code is it is making multiple web service call. Even if you call your print function in `.response` block it probably wont work as you think. It will print multiple times with different sizes.